# How to Retrieve Geographical Data from the US Geological Survey site?

Tags: linux, web-services, curl

The USGS has a page for user to make GET queries:

https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/

I attempted to fill the 4 fields provided:

X: -96.808971  // longitude

Y: 32.7792009  // Latitude

Units: Feet

Output: XML

After clicking on "Get Elevation" I get an error message:

"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below."

```
<USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service>
<Elevation_Query x="-96.808971" y="32.7792009">
<Data_Source>3DEP 1/3 arc-second</Data_Source>
<Elevation>420.61</Elevation>
<Units>Feet</Units>
</Elevation_Query>
</USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service>
```

They provide a sample URL GET:

"The following is a sample HTTP GET request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values."

```
GET pqs.php?x=string&y=string&units=string&output=string HTTP/1.1
Host: nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php
```

That is where I am stuck.

I have curl and and urlgrabber. Have only used them for simple requests.

TIA

Comment: If I select "JASON" in the Output field a better response is produced.

Comment: Why does the website software allow for multiple tags and a moderator will remove them? The welcoming message that I received from the site is at odds with the Draconian moderators. By removing two tags the moderator is reducing the chances of somebody answering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ curl 'https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=-96.808971&y=32.7792009&units=Feet&output=xml'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service><Elevation_Query x="-96.808971" y="32.7792009"><Data_Source>3DEP 1/3 arc-second</Data_Source><Elevation>420.61</Elevation><Units>Feet</Units></Elevation_Query></USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service>
```

if you want it prettified, you could use php to format it, eg:

```
$ curl 'https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=-96.808971&y=32.7792009&units=Feet&output=xml' -s | php -r '$domd=@DOMDocument::loadXML(stream_get_contents(STDIN));$domd->formatOutput=1;echo $domd->saveXML();'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service>
  <Elevation_Query x="-96.808971" y="32.7792009">
    <Data_Source>3DEP 1/3 arc-second</Data_Source>
    <Elevation>420.61</Elevation>
    <Units>Feet</Units>
  </Elevation_Query>
</USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service>
```

or if you just want the raw data, you can parse it with PHP like

```
curl 'https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=-96.808971&y=32.7792009&units=Feet&output=json' -s | php -r '$data=json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN));echo json_encode($data->USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service->Elevation_Query,-1);'
{
    "x": -96.808971,
    "y": 32.7792009,
    "Data_Source": "3DEP 1/3 arc-second",
    "Elevation": 420.61,
    "Units": "Feet"
}
```

.. or if you just want the elevation,

```
$ curl 'https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?x=-96.808971&y=32.7792009&units=Feet&output=json' -s | php -r '$data=json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN));echo $data->USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service->Elevation_Query->Elevation;'
420.61
```